# Magnific-Popup не добавляется class

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

Есть заявка, которая открывается AJAX' в поп-апе с помощью плагина Magnific-Popup.

```
<a href='/order/request-call.html' class='popup-ajax'>Написать письмо</a>

$('.popup-ajax').magnificPopup({
    preloader: true,
    type: 'ajax',
    removalDelay: 500,
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
});
```

Тут все ок.

Далее заполняем форму письма и кликаем отправить и вот тут при успешной отправке всплывает новая форма с сообщением, что все успешно отправлено.

Прописано что должен добавиться новый класс, но он не добавляется и поэтому не могу стилизовать форму с сообщением об успешной отправке.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#email').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var formdata = $('#email').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'add.php',
                    data: formdata,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.magnificPopup.open({
                            items: {
                                src: '<div class="form-style -modal">Ваше сообщение успешно отправленно</div>',
                                type: 'inline',
                                removalDelay: 500,
                                mainClass: 'mfp-success'
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

mainClass: 'mfp-success' - не работает

Всю голову сломал, так и не понял в чем проблема.
Возможно есть какой то другой способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.magnificPopup.instance.wrap.addClass('SuperClass'); - вообщем как вариант

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {

$(".forms").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
        $('.element-with-popup').magnificPopup({
        items: {
        src: '#test-popup',
        type: 'inline'
        }
        // (optionally) other options
        }).magnificPopup('open');
        setTimeout(function() {
        //$.magnificPopup.close();
        $(".forms").trigger("reset");
        }, 3000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});